# Getting the reversing function in R

Tags: r

i am trying to plot the reverse function of a given function in R:

```
f<-function(x){
if( x>1 || x< -1)
    {
       0
}else{
    0.75*(1-x^2)
}} #densityfunction f

fVec <- Vectorize(f)
F<-function(t){
    integrate(fVec, lower=-1, upper=t)$value
}#integral of f over interval -1,1

FVec<-Vectorize(F) #vectorize F

inverse <- function (f, lower = -1, upper = 1) {
   function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)$root
}

Finv = inverse(F, -1, 1)
FinvVec<-Vectorize(Finv) # Vectorize
#plot(FVec, xlim=c(-2, 2)) #plot F
plot(FinvVec, xlim=c(-2, 2)) #plot F inv
```

My problem is that i get the error:

```
Error  in uniroot((function(x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

AFAIK this means my function doesnt have a sign change. 
I asked my tutor and he told me there is a sign change and i´m doing something wrong here. But i just don´t know what. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the call to `uniroot` in a `try`, then it keeps going when it finds an error

```
inverse <- function (f, lower = -1, upper = 1) {
   function (y) try(uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)$root)
}
```

The resulting graph indicates that it only really works for x in (0,1).

```
plot(FinvVec, xlim=c(-2, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really new to r so sorry for this noobie question.